# Highlighting works incorrectly with media queries in sublime text 2

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

Whenever I create an `@media` in CSS and add tags behind it the first tag doesn't get highlighted.

[image: First it looks like this]
[image: Adding a new tag making the other work correctly]
[image: Continuously]

Is there any known way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have that problem so you could look into another theme. I also tested the current theme you have which did not cause the same problem.

**You can update your ST2 or look into another theme.**

Here are some great themes,

- Piatto
- Tomorrow color scheme
- Enlightened color scheme

If you have not setup your ST2's Package Control then here is a [great website](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/) to get it started.

Here is another Package Control [Link](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) from Sublime text. This site will always be up to date and includes info for both Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3.

Hit "Control + `" in sublime text and then add the following code,

```
import urllib2,os;pf='Package Control.sublime-package';ipp=sublime.installed_packages_path();os.makedirs(ipp) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None;open(os.path.join(ipp,pf),'wb').write(urllib2.urlopen('http://sublime.wbond.net/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())
```

Next just hit control + shift + p then type "install" to acces packages.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was but after following your instructions  all theme's worked perfectly fine for me. Odd if you ask me but thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: That is very odd! No problem, I am glad you got it working and best of luck!

Comment: @JoshPowell Good answer. In the future, though, I'd recommend sending people directly to the [Package Control Installation page](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) instead of a third-party site, as there is the (slight) possibility that the installation method may change over time. Additionally, the page I linked has instructions for ST2 and ST3, while the nettuts page is ST2-only.

Comment: @MattDMo Very good point! I will be adding that info to my answer, thank you!

Comment: @Josh_Powell It tends not to work every now and then. I checked and there are no available updates which means I cannot update it. It just requires me to restart whenever it's not working. Still weird because it doesn't work with the theme's you suggested either.

Comment: This may be a pain but, you can uninstall and re install ST2 if the problem still continues.

Comment: @Josh_Powell I'm fine with restarting it occasionally then ^^. When it really start bothering me I'll consider reinstalling it.

Comment: Alright! Well I wish I could have been of more help but at least it is manageable for now. :]